# Como "arredondar" um float em Python?

Tags: python, float, valor-monetário

Eu tenho esta soma:

```
total = 0.1 + 0.2
print total #retorna 0.30000000000000004
```

Como eu faria para "arredondar" as casas decimais e retornar apenas o número de casas somadas? Exemplo:

```
totalA = 0.1 + 0.2     #retornaria 0.3
totalB = 0.32 + 0.25   #retornaria 0.57
totalC = 0.358 + 0.1   #retornaria 0.458
#...
```

Comment: Sua dúvida é só como mostrar arrendondado ou está em dúvida porque ` 0.1 + 0.2` dá `0.30000000000000004` e não `0.3`?

Comment: @bigown É como mostrar arredondado.

Comment: Se for cálculo financeiro que estás tentando fazer não vá com float parta direto para Decimal para resolver esses problemas de arrendondamentos.
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html

Depois aplique o método especializado quantize() em conjunto com Rounding modes preferido.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Essa é uma dúvida recorrente. Este "problema" de arredondamento ocorre pela maneira como o número de ponto flutuante é armazenado e manipulado na própria CPU, e não depende do Python. O processador trabalha com ponto flutuante binário e não decimal, por isso há estes pequenas imprecisões. As linguagens acabam, por tabela, incorporando isto.

É muito rápido trabalhar com números assim e eles funcionam bem em muitos cenários. Quando você quer ter a precisão exata, provavelmente porque está trabalhando com valores monetários, precisa usar um [tipo decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) ou algo parecido que garanta a precisão necessária.

O que dá para fazer em Python ou qualquer linguagem é apresentar o número com a quantidade de casas decimais desejada. Na maioria das vezes apresentará o número que deseja. Não em todas.

Nessa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455634/221800) tem algumas alternativas para a apresentação:

```
>>> a=13.946
>>> print(a)
13.946
>>> print("%.2f" % a)
13.95
>>> round(a,2)
13.949999999999999
>>> print("%.2f" % round(a,2))
13.95
>>> print("{0:.2f}".format(a))
13.95
>>> print("{0:.2f}".format(round(a,2)))
13.95
>>> print("{0:.15f}".format(round(a,2)))
13.949999999999999
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Math/Round.py).

[Documentação da formatação](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Answer (score 10):

Muito simples:

```
def arredondar(num):
    return float( '%g' % ( num ) )
print(arredondar(0.1 + 0.2)
```

A saída: `0.3`.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar o .format 
Você vai por algo tipo: print("texto que vai utilizar {}".format(a variável que utilizou))
Note que dentro das aspas "" vão duas {} dentro das {} você porá {:.Nf} o "N" é um número que será arredondado, exemplo: print("O valor é: {:.2f}".format(sla))
Com isso a variável que eu chamei de sla vai ser aredondada dua casas depois da vírgula e caso queira também pode por apenas {:.f} que vai praticamente tirar o número e assim arredondar ele. 
Isso funciona para qualquer número que coloque antes do f dentro do {}

Answer (score 3):

utilize uma função de truncar

```
import math


def truncate(number, digits) -> float:
    stepper = pow(10.0, digits)
    return math.trunc(stepper * number) / stepper


print(truncate((0.1 + 0.2), 2))
```

Answer (score -4):

Você pode utilizar a função round(), que recebe o número a ser arredondado e o número de casas decimais que você quer arredondar para:

```python
>>> 0.1+0.2
0.300000000000000004

>>> # round com duas casas decimais:

>>> round(0.1+0.2,2)
0.3
```

Comment: Não é a melhor estratégia. A função round apresenta um problema, teste: `round(2.5)` , `round(2.51)` , `round(3.5)`  e `round(1.5)` veja que a função tem comportamento errático, com o motivo explicado [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44718/137387)