# Como obter resultados exatos de cálculos aritméticos simples?

Tags: matemática, float

Testei cálculos aritméticos simples em multiplex linguagens.

Testei alguns cálculos na consola python:

```
>>> 0.1+0.1
0.2
>>> 0.1+0.2
0.30000000000000004
>>> 10*0.67
6.7
>>> 10*0.68
6.800000000000001
>>> 10*0.69
6.8999999999999995
```

Também testei no javascript:

```
> 0.1 + 0.1
0.2 // correto
> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004 // erro
> 10 * 0.67
6.7 // correto
> 10 * 0.68
6.800000000000001 // erro
> 10 * 0.69
6.8999999999999995 // erro
```

No Fortran só piorou:

```
        real(kind=4)    :: soma, produto, soma1, produto1        
        soma = 0.1+0.1
        print *, '0.1+0.1 = ',soma 
        soma = 0.1+0.2
        print *, '0.1+0.2 = ',soma 

        produto = 10*0.67
        print *, '10*0.67 = ', produto  
        produto = 10*0.68
        print *, '10*0.68 = ', produto
        produto = 10*0.69
        print *, '10*0.69 = ', produto
        print *,'' 

        soma1 = 0.1d0+0.1d0
        print *, '0.1d0+0.2d0 = ',soma1
        soma1 = 0.1d0+0.2d0
        print *, '0.1d0+0.2d0 = ',soma1

        produto1 = 10.d0*0.67d0
        print *, '10.d0*0.67d0 = ', produto1
        produto1 = 10.d0*0.68d0
        print *, '10.d0*0.68d0 = ', produto1
        produto1 = 10.d0*0.69d0
        print *, '10.d0*0.69d0 = ', produto1
        print *,'' 

        soma1 = 0.1_8+0.1_8
        print *, '0.1_8+0.1_8 = ',soma1
        soma1 = 0.1_8+0.2_8
        print *, '0.1_8+0.1_8 = ',soma1

        produto1 = 10_8*0.67_8
        print *, '10_8*0.67_8 = ', produto1
        produto1 = 10_8*0.68_8
        print *, '10_8*0.68_8 = ', produto1
        produto1 = 10_8*0.69_8
        print *, '10_8*0.69_8 = ', produto1
```

A saída:

```
 0.1+0.1 =   0.200000003    
 0.1+0.2 =   0.300000012    
 10*0.67 =    6.70000029    
 10*0.68 =    6.80000019    
 10*0.69 =    6.90000010    

 0.1d0+0.2d0 =   0.200000003    
 0.1d0+0.2d0 =   0.300000012    
 10.d0*0.67d0 =    6.69999981    
 10.d0*0.68d0 =    6.80000019    
 10.d0*0.69d0 =    6.90000010    

 0.1_8+0.1_8 =   0.200000003    
 0.1_8+0.1_8 =   0.300000012    
 10_8*0.67_8 =    6.69999981    
 10_8*0.68_8 =    6.80000019    
 10_8*0.69_8 =    6.90000010
```

A causa do problema já foi explicada na pergunta [Resultado impreciso em cálculo com números quebrados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642/resultado-impreciso-em-c%C3%A1lculo-com-n%C3%BAmeros-quebrados) mas porque as calculadoras não sobrem esse problema.

Existe forma de obter resultados tão bons quanto uma calculadora do caixa do mercado, com estas linguagens?

Comment: Excelente leitura [Por que os computadores são uma droga em matemática? no Coding Horror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/why-do-computers-suck-at-math/) (inglês). Em suma, números reais frequentemente têm dígitos infinitos. Computadores são incríveis, mas não infinitos. O melhor que eles podem fazer é aproximar.

Comment: O computador não faz nada errado, a linguagem também não, bom tem linguagem que até faz, mas é raro, é discutível e não é o caso. Então só sobra o programador mesmo por usar a ferramenta errada. Quando se deseja exatidão não se usa ponto flutuante e sim um decimal, conforme essa resposta para Python: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44718/101. também em: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101

Comment: Mesmo com a edição que descaracteriza a pergunta original, ainda assim é continua duplicata. Estou propenso a mudar a original que indica o que fazer para resolver o problema, mas como é minha vou evitar. De qualquer forma toda informação para resolver isso está *linkado* aqui.

Comment: Eu li aquela resposta mas não me diz como realizar um calculo exato no python. La realmente responde o porque? Foi enriquecedor le-lo, mas como faço eu, para calcular, existe uma função especial para contornar essa situação. O sera melhor eu pegar minha casio e calcular na mão...