# Formatar valor em pyhton

Tags: python

Tenho um crawler onde eu pego valores nesse formato: "R$ 450,000.00".

Mas preciso converter esses valores em float e salvar no banco de dados para fazer consultas desse tipo: Pegar os valores que estão entre 40.000,00 e 100.000,00.

Comment: Posta o que você tem. A parte que pega os dados e salva no banco de dados.

Comment: A resposta precisa incluir o trecho relacionado ao banco de dados, ou apenas a conversão de tipos?

Comment: Primeira coisa que precisa saber: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44715/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
valorRaw = 'R$ 450,000.00'
valor = float(valor.split('$')[1].replace(',', '')) # 450000.0
```

Partindo do princípio que tens a certeza que os valores vêm sempre nesse formato

OU:

```
valorRaw = 'R$ 450,000.00'
valor = float(valor[2:].replace(',', '')) # 450000.0
```

`[2:]` quer dizer que queremos tudo a partir do index 2 ("$") e depois retiramos a virgula caso haja