# Conversão de valores incorreta em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho um crawler que pega o valor **STRING** **R$ 560.000,00**.

Preciso converter esse valor para **FLOAT** porque vou utilizar este valor para realizar consultas, desse tipo:

```
Selecionar todos os carros com o valor entre 100000 até 560000
```

Estou convertendo o valor desse jeito:

```
float(price[2:].replace(',', ''))
```

E ele está convertendo o valor R$ 560.000,00 para 560.0

Gostaria dos valores convertidos assim:

- R$ 17.000,00 para 17000
- R$ 100.000,00 para 100000
- R$ 560.000,00 para
  560000

Comment: Seria bom saber sobre isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44715/101

Comment: Mas queres que seja para float? Ou int? Os exemplos que apresentas são convertidos para int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não seria uma boa dar `replace` no ponto também? 100.000 vai ser igual a 100 reais e não a 100 mil reais.

```
float(price[2:].replace('.', ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

A [resposta da colega @Priscilla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/174882/73) é suficiente e, de fato, a melhor escolha para a grande maioria dos casos. Porém, se o seu *crowler* precisar lidar com dinheiro em diferentes formatos, pode ser útil você considerar a localidade/idioma da página acessada. Uma forma de fazer isso é utilizando o pacote `locale`.

Eis um exemplo de código ilustrativo:

```
import re
import locale

#--------------------------------------------------
def extractMonetaryValue(text):

    cs = locale.localeconv()['currency_symbol']
    expr = '{}[ ]*[0-9.,]+'.format(cs.replace('$', '\\$'))

    m = re.search(expr, text)
    if m:
        s = m.group(0).replace(cs, '').replace(' ', '')
        return locale.atof(s)
    else:
        return 0.0
#--------------------------------------------------

s = 'Este teste testa um valor (por exemplo: R$ 560.200,40) expresso em Reais.'
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ptb_bra') # 'pt_BR' se não estiver no Windows
n = extractMonetaryValue(s)
print('Para "{}" o valor é: {}'.format(s, n))

s = 'This test tests a value (let us say U$ 482,128.33) given in US Dolars.'
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'enu_usa') # 'en_US' se não estiver no Windows
n = extractMonetaryValue(s)
print('Para "{}" o valor é: {}'.format(s, n))
```

Nesse código, o principal é a função `extractMonetaryValue`. Ela recebe um texto qualquer e procura nele por um subtexto que contenha, *necessariamente*, o símbolo monetário do país/idioma configurado (seguido de zero ou mais espaços), e então um número composto de dígitos, pontos e vírgulas. Para tal, ela usa uma expressão regular *bem abrangente*: ela não se preocupa se o "formato" numérico está correto ou não, pois isso será feito depois, pela chamada de [`locale.atof`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.atof) (que lança a exceção `ValueError` se o formato estiver incorreto de acordo com o país/idioma configurados).

A saída do código acima é a seguinte:

```
Para "Este teste testa um valor (por exemplo: R$ 560.200,40) expresso em Reais." o valor é: 560200.4
Para "This test tests a value (let us say U$ 482,128.33) given in US Dolars." o valor é: 482128.33
```

Repare como os números impressos no final usam ambos o ponto como separador decimal (afinal, são valores representados como `float` internamente, da mesma forma independentemente da origem tratada).

> P.S.:
>
> 1. Para detectar o `locale` padrão do sistema operacional, use `locale.getdefaultlocale()`
> 2. Para detectar o `locale` de uma página web, verifique se ela tem essa infomação [na tag
>      `lang`](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations).
>      Se ela não tiver, você precisará tentar inferir o idioma. Pra sua
>      (nossa! hehe) sorte, há [esse porte do detector de idiomas do Google
>      para Python chamado
>      `langdetect`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect).