# Calculo de Seno com Python

Tags: python, matemática

Olá, eu estou com um problema no calculo de seno utilizando o pyhton, eu montei uma função para o calculo do seno e coseno, porém o resultado está vindo errado para o seno, enquanto o coseno o resultado está certo. Acabei descobrindo que o seno funciona se eu calculo com 60 graus(o meu teste era sen(30) e cos(60) onde ambos devem resultar em 0.5 ou algo próximo), minha teoria é que ele funcione com valores maiores que 1 rad.
aqui estão os resultados no console (seno(30) e coseno(60) respectivamente)

```
0.9909847665675204
-0.4999999999999262
```

e aqui estão os códigos

```
def converterGrausParaRad(numero):
    rad = (numero/180)*const_Pi()
    return rad
    #abaixo: definição da função seno por sin² + cos² = 1

def seno(numero):
    resultado = 0
    resultado = raizQuadrada(1 - (coseno(numero))**2)
    return resultado

#abaixo:definição da função coseno pela sua expanção da serie de taylor



def coseno(rad):
    numero = converterGrausParaRad(rad)
    cont = 0
    resultado = 0
    while(cont < 50):
        cont += 1
        resultado += (((-1)**cont)*(numero**(2 * cont)))/(fatorial(2 * cont))
    return resultado
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O problema é que o cálculo da aproximação do cosseno está incorreto. Se você observar a [série de Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Series_definitions) do cosseno, verá que o valor começa com 1 - **mas você inicia a variável `resultado` com 0**. Basta alterar para `resultado = 1` que (essa parte) vai funcionar.

Aí você vai ter outro problema, relacionado à precisão. A aproximação por esse método gera alguns errinhos, e quando o cosseno resulta em 1 pode ocorrer da sua função retornar 1.00000000000001. Nesse caso, a raiz que você tenta calcular na função seno vai gerar um número complexo (uma vez que 1 - 1.00000000000001 vai dar um número negativo). Por isso uma outra alteração útil é você arredondar o retorno da sua função cosseno em algumas casas decimais (acho que 6 casas tá bom).

O código alterado segue abaixo. Mas observe que você **não preparou um exemplo funcional**: muitas das suas funções não estão no código. Por isso, pra testar, eu alterei usando as do pacote `math`. O código, aliás, compara o seu cálculo com os do pacote `math` para ilustrar a corretude.

```
import math

def converterGrausParaRad(numero):
    rad = (numero/180)*math.pi
    return rad
    #abaixo: definição da função seno por sin² + cos² = 1

def seno(numero):
    resultado = 0
    resultado = math.sqrt(1 - (coseno(numero))**2)
    return resultado

#abaixo:definição da função coseno pela sua expanção da serie de taylor

def coseno(rad):
    numero = converterGrausParaRad(rad)
    cont = 0
    resultado = 1 # ERRO!!!
    while(cont < 50):
        cont += 1
        resultado += (((-1)**cont)*(numero**(2 * cont)))/(math.factorial(2 * cont))

    return round(resultado, 6) # MELHORIA

angles = [i for i in range(0, 181, 15)]
for angle in angles:
    sin = seno(angle)
    cos = coseno(angle)
    sin_ = math.sin(converterGrausParaRad(angle))
    cos_ = math.cos(converterGrausParaRad(angle))
    print('ângulo: {} seno: {:.4f} ({:.4f}) cosseno: {:.4f} ({:.4f})' \
                .format(angle, sin, sin_, cos, cos_))
```

Resultado:

```
ângulo: 0 seno: 0.0000 (0.0000) cosseno: 1.0000 (1.0000)
ângulo: 15 seno: 0.2588 (0.2588) cosseno: 0.9659 (0.9659)
ângulo: 30 seno: 0.5000 (0.5000) cosseno: 0.8660 (0.8660)
ângulo: 45 seno: 0.7071 (0.7071) cosseno: 0.7071 (0.7071)
ângulo: 60 seno: 0.8660 (0.8660) cosseno: 0.5000 (0.5000)
ângulo: 75 seno: 0.9659 (0.9659) cosseno: 0.2588 (0.2588)
ângulo: 90 seno: 1.0000 (1.0000) cosseno: 0.0000 (0.0000)
ângulo: 105 seno: 0.9659 (0.9659) cosseno: -0.2588 (-0.2588)
ângulo: 120 seno: 0.8660 (0.8660) cosseno: -0.5000 (-0.5000)
ângulo: 135 seno: 0.7071 (0.7071) cosseno: -0.7071 (-0.7071)
ângulo: 150 seno: 0.5000 (0.5000) cosseno: -0.8660 (-0.8660)
ângulo: 165 seno: 0.2588 (0.2588) cosseno: -0.9659 (-0.9659)
ângulo: 180 seno: 0.0000 (0.0000) cosseno: -1.0000 (-1.0000)
```

Se você for usar a fórmula geral (tá lá no mesmo link da Wikipedia), aí então **precisa** iniciar o fator (`cont`) em 0 (porque -1 elevado a 0 é 0, que é positivo, e o cálculo da primeira interação resulta em 1). Aí, é só mover a linha que soma 1 na variável `cont` para **após** o cálculo do fator atual:

```
def coseno(rad):
    numero = converterGrausParaRad(rad)
    cont = 0
    resultado = 0
    while(cont < 50):
        resultado += (((-1)**cont)*(numero**(2 * cont)))/(math.factorial(2 * cont))
        cont += 1 # MOVIDO P/ APÓS O CÁLCULO

    return round(resultado, 6)
```

> Observação:
>
> A sua ideia de alternar o sinal usando -1 elevado ao fator é bem
>   inteligente. :) Mas tenha em mente que o operador `**` é computacionalmente custoso. Uma
>   sugestão que deve ser mais eficiente é fazer da seguinte forma (usando
>   o operador de potenciação somente uma vez):
>
> ```
> def coseno(rad):
>     numero = converterGrausParaRad(rad)
>     signal = -1
>     resultado = 1
>     factors = [i for i in range(2, 50, 2)]
>     for f in factors:
>         resultado += signal * ((numero ** f) / math.factorial(f) )
>         signal *= -1
>
>     return round(resultado, 6)
> ```

Comment: Obrigado Luiz, a formula para o calculo eu tirei do LEITHOLD vol 2 segunda edição pagina 590, acabei de sair de calculo 4 e quis experimentar e fui seguir o livro. desculpe por não enviar as funções eu estava frustrado com o código e acabei esquecendo (sou novo no stack),  sobre o resultado, eu estava querendo uma precisão maior, porém eu não sei como manipular a precisão no python, você tem algum material para indicar? novamente obrigado!

Comment: Por nada. Talvez (dependendo da precisão que você desejar) você consiga controlando no `round` que eu usei ali. Se não, vai ter que usar uma abordagem como a descrita aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44715/como-arredondar-um-float-em-python#comment239121_44715 (sugerindo o módulo [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html)).