# Preciso de ajuda sobre a estrutura 'if e else'

Tags: python, if, else

Criei duas estruturas 'if e else' para fazer com que o programa escreva para o usuário usando o plural corretamente e como podem ver abaixo, criei duas variáveis dentro das estruturas para atribuir o plural que o programa decidir. Existe alguma maneira de atribuir os valores a duas variáveis dentro de uma só estrutura? Fazer algo como:

```
if m > 1: b = metros, c = centimetros?
```

Como não sei qual valor o usuário irá fornecer, decidi declarar a variável como `float`, porém como `float` são os números reais, caso o usuário digite um número inteiro, o resultado ficará com .0 no final. Para isso não acontecer, eu precisaria criar outra estrutura `if` e `else`?

Estou usando o Python 3.7 e o IDE PyCharm.

> Faça um Programa que converta metros para centímetros.

```
m = float(input('Insira a medida em metros: '))

b = 'd'

if m > 1:
    b = 'metros'

else:
    b = 'metro'

if m > 1:
    d = 'equivalem'

else:
    d = 'equivale'


c = m * 100

print(f'{m} {b} {d} a {c} centimetros')
```

Comment: Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101

Comment: Relacionada: [Números e plural](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1081/1767)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site.

Answer (score 4):

Pode fazer sim:

```
if m > 1:
    b = 'metros'
    d = 'equivalem'
else:
    b = 'metro'
    d = 'equivale'
```

Se vai usar as palavras em sequência, então nem tem porque manter duas variáveis:

```
if m > 1:
    b = 'metros equivalem'
else:
    b = 'metro equivale'
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/SameConditional.py).

Acho que seria melhor usar nomes de variáveis mais significativos.

Já pensou que a pessoa pode digitar 0? Qual solução quer dar para isto? Vai pluralizar?

Você pode fazer isto de uma forma mais moderna e correta, mas preferi não introduzir essas coisas para você agora.

O arredondamento já foi respondido em [Como "arredondar" um float em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44715/101).