# Gostaria de saber como escrevo >>> print("Tamanho = %4.2f cm" % Tamanho) e o que significa o %4.2f

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Estou fazendo uma tarefa da faculdade e gostaria de saber o que significa o `%4.2f` em `>>> print("Tamanho = %4.2f cm" % Tamanho)` e como é representado um valor (8.47826) seguindo tal parâmetro após o programa rodar

Comment: `%4.2f` = F é do tipo `float`, `4` significa pelo menos 4 caracteres; o `2`significa duas casa decimais após a virgula.

Comment: >>> print("Tamanho = %4.2f cm" % Tamanho) A tarefa consiste em representar o número 8.47826 dentro dessa linha de programação. No entanto, quando tento Tamanho = 8.47 cm aparece que está errado. não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: Entendi, você quer o arrendondar para baixo: leia esta pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44715/como-arredondar-um-float-em-python?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: consegui já, mas muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que você tenha o seguinte código:

```py
Tamanho = 8.4726
print("Tamanho = %4.2f cm" % Tamanho)
```

Então o retorno do print utilizando a variável Tamanho de valor 8.4726 seria:

Tamanho = 8.47 cm

Comment: já consegui! muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Isso se chama formatação, isso quer dizer que você está dizendo ao python que a formatação de saída da variável `Tamanho` que será exibida na função `print()` possuirá no máximo 4 casas antes da vírgula e 2 casas depois da vírgula. `%` indica o início da formação e `f` o tipo de varável que você está formatando, ou seja, `float`.

Porém essa é uma formatação bastante antiga, hoje o mais usado é `.format()`  dê uma olhada nessa documentação aqui:

https://pyformat.info